# Getting error in cron job using struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, cron

Am trying to use cron job using struts 2 framework. I tried with this example from [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-quartz-scheduler-integration-example/)
for understanding. The source as follows,

```
//SchedulerJob.java
public class SchedulerJob implements Job {
      public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)throws JobExecutionException {
               System.out.println("Struts 2.3.4 + Quartz 2.1.5");
}}


//QuartzSchedulerListener.java
public class QuartzSchedulerListener implements ServletContextListener {
     public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {//....}
     public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
     JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(SchedulerJob.class).withIdentity("anyJobName", "group1").build();
//.....}}
```

In the line `JobDetail` am getting error stating

```
no suitable method found for newJob(Class<SchedulerJob>)
method JobBuilder.newJob(Class<? extends Job>) is not applicable
(actual argument Class<SchedulerJob> cannot be converted to Class<? extends Job> by method invocation conversion)
 method JobBuilder.newJob() is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Suggest me an idea to solve this. Let me know if any sample sources available for cron jobs using struts 2 for better understanding.

Comment: Do you need to use `quartz`? Do you have `spring` in your stack?

Comment: Am not using spring in my stack. when i was searching for how to cron in struts 2 i got that quartz.

Comment: hard to guess what went wrong! Are there 2 Job classes/interfaces in your application ?

Comment: @coding_idiot   what you mean by 2 job classes? To my understanding am using the `schedulerJob.java` class as described above. You may get an idea if you visit the link [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-quartz-scheduler-integration-example/)

Comment: `Class<? extends Job>` which job is it ? & `SchedulerJob implements Job` which job is here ? (full package urls)